# Why do we set node.fs: 'empty' in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fs

I see this error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ....." and is solution is

```
// webpack 4
node: {
    fs: "empty"
}


//webpack5
   resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css"],
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
    },
  },
```

However I have no idea what does "fs:false" or "empty" mean?

Comment: Have you read https://webpack.js.org/configuration/?

Answer (score 2):

It means the same thing. Sometimes few modules use native Node.js module like `fs` which Webpack attempts to bundle when bundling for browser environment. Since, `fs` is not available or simply doesn't make any sense for browser environment, Webpack throws the module not found error.

Specifying the value of `"empty"` or `false` for `fs` is telling Webpack to ignore that module and not attempt to bundle it.

**Why this happens?** Some modules are isomorphic meaning that support both browser and node.js. The bundler like Webpack cannot simply figure out the if native module should be excluded or not. (With ESM Modules, tree shaking and `sideEffect`, Webpack can handle this well to a great extent.)

Comment: FS could easily be included in the browser if the user gives real/write permission via showdirectorypicker or using the sandbox directory in navigator.